# How to set the starting position of the grid line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a grid line. But I don't like the grid lines start from 0.

```
miloc = plt.MultipleLocator(1)
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
```

This will generate grid lines at 0,1,2,3,4.... .
But I want to generate grid lines at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5? is there any method? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AutoMinorLocator`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

# Rest of the code

minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(2)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
plt.grid(which='minor')
```